# select query, compare null records

Tags: sql-server, select, null

I'm writing an sql server query:

```
select * from vwApplicationList
            where status='Unassigned' AND
            BBL like '%' + @BBL + '%' AND
            UnitOrAppartmentNumber like '%'+@Appartment+'%' AND
            ResidenceTypeDescription like '%'+@ResidenceTypeDescription+'%' AND
            SN1 like '%'+@SN1+'%' AND
            SN2 like '%'+@SN2+'%'
```

The problem is that the field "SN2" is null in several records. So how can I compare them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a positive result on the comparison:

```
... AND COALESCE(SN2, @SN2) LIKE '%' + @SN2 + '%'
```

If you want a negative result (assuming `@SN2` is not also an empty string):

```
... AND COALESCE(SN2, '') LIKE '%' + @SN2 + '%'
```

Comment: Would not the code as currently written exclude all rows where SN2 is null?

Comment: I could be wrong, but won't this prevent the use of an index that contains SN2?

Comment: @PhilipKelley: Indeed it would.

Comment: @cadrell0: The leading wild card on the LIKE comparison is already going to kill any chance of using an index.

Answer (score 3):

you can do

```
COALESCE(SN2 ,'') like '%'+@SN2+'%'
```

[COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` and only be compared with `IS NOT` and `IS NOT NULL`.

If you want to always include NULL you could try

```
(SN2 like '%'+@SN2+'%' OR SN2 IS NULL)
```

If you only want to include NULL when @SN2 is empty, try something like

```
(SN2 like '%'+@SN2+'%' OR (@SN2 = '' AND SN2 IS NULL))
```